# Hls fast recconect

Tags: javascript, video, http-live-streaming

In the hls documentation, it is recommended to use this function for error cases

```js
case Hls.ErrorTypes.MEDIA_ERROR:
 console.log("fatal media error encountered, try to recover");
 hls.recoverMediaError();
        break;
```

https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#hlsrecovermediaerror

However, in the case of live, it takes a long time to recover the video in case of error or transmission failure. Is there a way to recover the transmission more quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the documentation or demo source code you'll notice that both are suggesting to call recover media error if any media related error occurred.

- Now what this recoverMediaError will do, is it will remove the video element and append it back.
- This method has few backdrops

  - If a subtitle is selected then all its cue will be lost
  - since the element is removed there will be a blank screen without a video thumbnail or loader
  - this makes the process longer

After a few experiment, this is what I Prefer to resolve the errors

- instead of calling recoverMediaError we can call the startLoad() function which will start the loading of the current segment
- this function is suitable as it will keep your video element at its place and also will show a loader

Besides that, you can make a function which will first call the startLoad still if the error raised then your final option should be calling recoverMediaError()

Comment: I used `startLoad` instead of `recoverMediaError` but it will play old segment of first load, example current time is 12:00:00 I got media error, then it will replay on 11:30:00 (first time hls load). Have anyway to resolve this issue?